# What happens if I attempt to delete Ubuntu itself while logged in?

Tags: directory, root, delete

What would happen if I delete the `/` directory while logged as root into Ubuntu?

Would I get some sort of error to the effect of `Error: unable to self-destruct`? Or would I actually be able to delete the directory?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/641954/295286  Check the comments bellow my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did try this out on a live USB for answering [a question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-will-happen-if-I-go-the-root-directory-in-Linux-Mac-and-type-the-command-rm-rf-forcibly-remove-all-directories-and-subdirectories) some time ago (there's another great answer there by Eric Bowersox).

First attempt on an installed system where I was confident nothing would happen:

```
# cd /
# rm -rf /
rm: it is dangerous to operate recursively on `/'
rm: use --no-preserve-root to override this failsafe
# rm -rf .
rm: cannot remove directory: `.'
#
```

So, I tried it on a live USB (quoting from my original post):

> Eric Bowersox inspired me to try it out on a live USB (without
>   persistence). Like he said, a huge number of errors about files
>   currently being used, plus another huge set of errors about the
>   read-only file system being used ended up with parts of the GUI
>   vanishing in stages: first the icons in the Unity launcher, then the
>   icon for the HUD, then icons in the system tray. When it all ended
>   (remarkably quickly), only the terminal could focused, clicking
>   anywhere else didn't work. I could open anything else, not even the
>   preferences of the terminal. Menus of the localization and the clock
>   applets opened, but didn't work.
>
> Switching to the other ttys worked once (I didn't get around to trying
>   any commands), but once I switched back to the GUI, nothing worked.
>
> Here's how it looked then: [image]
>
> Nothing worked at this point. Except for the power button and the
>   Magic SysRq keys.

---

Deleting the shared libraries or `rm` itself shouldn't cause any problems, since both would have been loaded into memory when `rm` started.

Comment: [Turns out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2025479/4316166) shared libraries might be loaded only upon requirement (FWIW to expand your last snippet more in depth, since basically you answered the question already)

Answer (score 5):

So I did it in a running *Ubuntu 14.10* VM inside *Virtualbox*. I did not bother to install it myself but downloaded one directly from [osboxes.org](http://www.osboxes.org/)

Running `sudo rm -rf --no-preserve-root /` in a terminal caused this:

- Some buttons began to disappear in the launcher
- Then the launcher was gone
- And finally all the desktop with the terminal running disappeared
- Left with a total blue screen (sic)[image: bsod]

That was only the visible part. I didn't let it run very long and  shut down the machine.

So `rm` was not completely succesfull because there was some files lying around still: /bin, /run, some part of /lib, and /var

But no /boot and no kernel left so it was no bootable again even though the modules were still there.

**Edit**:
Doing it from a *console* (Ctrl-Alt-F1 or Right-Ctrl F1 in vbox) is much more sucessfull though less spectacular.

It spits out errors about /sys file it can't delete , the same in /proc. But there is nothing left after it completes. Only some devices under /dev and some files in /run.

Comment: "But there is nothing left after it completes." ... How did you find that out? Did you have a static-linked busybox shell running?

Comment: I just mounted the virtual disk in another VM to check it out.

Comment: `/proc` and `/sys` are virtual filesystems populated by the kernel. Files in it do not exist on disk.

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT EVER DO THIS, but if you did `sudo rm -rf /` the `rm` command, running as `root`, would happily start deleting. If it found a file, it would delete it,. If `rm` found a directory, it would enter the directory, delete all the files, then delete the directory. Eventually, `rm` will run out of files to delete, or will delete a file `rm` needs (like a dynamic library):

```
$ ldd $( type -p rm)
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd4a978000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f905b7be000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f905bbcc000)
```

When `rm` deletes `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` or `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` it will probably break.

Linux takes its philosophy from Unix: "Powerful tools are powerful, keep fingers out of the machinery".

Comment: So in reality, it wouldn't be possible to completely remove the `/` directory?

Comment: Not that way. You could, using this technique, reduce a system to the non-working state.

Comment: Once the command has loaded the needed dll, there is no need for it to access it on disk after that because it's in ram and the command can complete even if the library is not there anymore. So I think this is wrong. It will not stop until everything is gone. However every other command that you will try to run will not find the libc and fail. Also this will not work 'as is' because you need to add a switch to really run that command.

Comment: @solsTiCe Shared libraries AFAIK might be loaded only when effectively needed, but I might be wrong on this, since it's just something I've read somewhere once. Howerver @ waltinator solsTiCe it's surely right about the fact that `sudo rm -rf /` it's disabled by default, you alsoneed to add the `--no-preserve-root` switch to make it actually run.

Comment: @solsTiCe as I have come to understand "rm" can/might be reloaded during its progress and error out.

Comment: @kos I myself do not mind this. Better a none working rm than a working rm ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind Indeed, just for the sake of discussing :)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2025479/4316166)'s more about the loading behavior of shared libraries; it looks like they might be loaded only when required.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to remove the / folder and all subfolders, you could boot to a Live PenDrive and use Gparted to remove the partition that / is on and rebuild it, if that is what you want.  If you want all other folders under root that are on separate partitions, you could do the same with the other partitions.  You just can't do it on purpose from the command line when that's where you booted from.

Comment: If the goal is to wipe the drive, why not just boot a liveDisk and run #shred -f /dev/sdb