# If I (Theoretically, never actually would) pulled out the boot disk of a Ubuntu 16.04 machine, what would happen as it began to fail?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, crash, hotplug, stress-testing

Obviously it will stop working.. but what would go first, how long till it halts etc. Lets say we're at the desktop with no running programs. Assuming disk is **not** hot-pluggable.

Comment: Pretty much the same things as in http://askubuntu.com/a/652232/158442

Comment: Posts like that always make me think of this story: http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/hack/recovery.html

Answer (score 1):

The system shouldn't halt, because the critical software is loaded into memory. You'd get lots of errors and most things wouldn't work.

Comment: That's not entirely true. Some programs and shared libraries may have been discarded (partially) from main memory to make space for more recently used things. A later access to these virtual memory pages would cause a hard page fault that is now unsatisfiable because the underlying storage device is no more. I'm not sure how the kernel reacts to that but falls somewhere between between a forceful termination of the page-faulting process and a kernel panic.